# Ruby on Rails: Find maximum integer inside a row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

does anyone know how to fetch the maximum value out of this **row** in rails?
I need to get the maximum value of a `cat_`

*Model: CategoryVote*

```
id:integer

cat_2:integer
cat_3:integer
.
.
cat_13:integer
```

Is there a function like maximum of (cat_2,cat_3...)?

Thank you

Comment: I guess I found this http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CategoryVote.pluck(:id, "greatest(cat_2, cat_3, ..., cat_13)")
```